# Schema Dump Without User Mapping Passwords

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pg-dump

Is it possible to do a `pg_dump --schema-only` of the database schema but not include any username/password combinations that are in user mappings?

For example, I would like items such as the following to not be put in the dump:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR greg SERVER db_name OPTIONS (
    password 'supersecret',
    username 'bobs_uncle'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to create a single-purpose non-super user and grant them read access to all the objects in the database.  Then run `pg_dump` connected as that user. Perhaps not the most elegant solution.